# Adding Printer on MacOS 11.5.1 BigSur

Tags: macos, printing

I need to add a printer to my M1 Mac running 11.5.1 MacOS. Everytime I try I get an error:

Bad File Descriptor

I have tried multiple different printers - at home and in the office, both AirPrint or PostScript. Always the same error.

printers are always connected via local network and available - can access their IP via a browser. They do show up with Bonjourn when I try to add but always ends with the error. Tried resetting the printer system via right click
/Library/Printers/ has no mention of any printer installed (trying HP m277dw at home)

[image]

[image]

EDIT: found a way to continue with the HP Easy Start. It downloads the essentials software, install works but fails when adding:

[image]

I am now convinced it's the same error as when adding from the Mac system settings - the "bad descriptor". Not sure where to go next...

Comment: Run HP's Easy Start, otherwise you don't get a proper printer description set up, you end up with 'Generic Postscript' as in your picture.

Comment: Thanks but Easy Start will only redirect to Install the HP Smart. I tried that and same as many users it will not launch and crash immediately: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-Copying/HP-Smart-App-won-t-load-for-Mac-Catalina-OS-10-15-7/td-p/8059338/page/4

Comment: HP had a Certificate issue a year or so ago - which was fixed by a joint effort between them & Apple. The latest versions should be fine, as far as I know. My main Mac [still on Mojave] still has the older structure because I didn't see the issue, but my newest, an M1 on Big Sur, had no issues with the new installer.

Comment: Edited above - still no print capability :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to fix it today by:

1. Deleting all of the installed software (both HP Smart from AppStore and Easy start)
2. Updating my Mac to 11.5.2
3. Restart as required
4. Installing HP Smart again
5. I was able to add the printer

Seems like there was a bug in the 11.5.1

[image]